# Ansible roles to create Image

Tags: docker, ansible, packer, docker-image, ansible-container

I'm using Ansible for deployment on cloud/bare metal servers.

I would like to take it to next step and create a docker image of existing playbook I have which consists multiple roles and later run it on the cloud/bare metal server with possible implementation on k8s.

What I would like to know is what is the best way to do that?

I know I should start firstly with containerizing and later get it connected with k8s but I would like to know if there are any best practices and what is the best way to do so especially for the first part - containerizing existing roles. 
I did read about Ansible-container, ansible and docker module, creating of container images using Buildah and Ansible, creating images using Packer and Ansible.

There seem to be various ways to achieve my goal, any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!